# How to make JTextArea non-Selectable

Tags: java, swing

i want to display a textarea decribing the value of a node ( a graph project)
but whenever i select the text it gets messy so i want it to be unsectable ! 
this is the code :

```
public class TransparentTextArea extends JTextArea {

String texte;

public TransparentTextArea(String texte) {
    this.setLineWrap(true);
    this.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    this.texte = texte;
    this.setBackground(new Color(255, 0, 9, 0));
    this.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 24));
    this.setEditable(false);
    this.setText(texte);
    this.setSize(new Dimension(200,100 ));
  } 
}
```

thx

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's somehow old question but for those who still care, disabling the `JTextArea` is not very helpful, mostly because of the gray color of the foreground. The best thing to do, is to nullify the highlighter:

```
setHighlighter(null)
```

Comment: Thanks I was reading your answers and I found this really helpfull 

Answer (score 4):

First of all, I know that this is very old post, but I really had to answer, since I had the same question and found the answer, and the given answers are not 100%.

Stelios said that we cat set `setHighlighter(null);` but it is still selectable and we can even copy-paste. And there is no need to `setEnabled(false);`, especially when the look and feel is awful

The answer that I found is very simple.

```java
jtextPane.setEditable( false );
jtextPane.getCaret().deinstall( jtextPane );
```

Comment: Nice thought, but if you do this and navigate to the JTextArea with `Tab` and then try to select select the text with `Ctrl + A` then you will get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to have the `JTextArea` selectable, then the simplest thing to do is to disable it:

```
setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I agree with `setEnabled(false)` but setting the color is a bad idea. Depending on the look-and-feel, black might be a color that stands out. setEnabled false should be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using both `setEditable` and `setFocusable` prevent the selection, while still allowing to style with colors the text.

```java
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea("Static text");
textArea.setEditable(false);
textArea.setFocusable(false);

JTextField textField = new JTextField("Static text");
textField.setEditable(false);
textField.setFocusable(false);
```

Answer (score -4):

When the text of a text area is set, all text is deselected. Something like this:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    while (true) {
        textArea.setText(textArea.getText());
    }
});
t.start();
```

Comment: Your solution is not viable. Why should I have a thread, with no control whatsoever, constantly copy-pasting the text? That would make an application really slow.